# Normalization of binary data SVM Multi Class

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I have some features to normalize (near 10), some of them are continious values and I normalize them with the function `prepocessing` of Scikit-learn `( x(i) - mean.x)/std.x` for all `i` in `{1,...n}`.

But I have a important feature who takes only two values : 1 or 0 and which is very important for my study.
Do you think that I have to normalize it or it is not necessary for the SVM or others ML algorithms like Random forests?

Thanks you !

Comment: If your feature takes only 0 or 1, it must be categorical. No need to normalize it.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking but there is not a risk of over-weighting ?

Comment: I don't think so. Just define those features as categorical before feeding them to model.